# How do I update an external DIV when a user swipes the finger along an Highcharts Area graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating an Area Chart with HighCharts and I need to update a div with several values from the chart when a user swipes the  finger across the graph.

The values from the chart must be consistent with the values shown on the tooltip.

Is there a specific event I can use for this?

Here is an example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Sources: <a href="https://thebulletin.org/2006/july/global-nuclear-stockpiles-1945-2006">' +
            'thebulletin.org</a> &amp; <a href="https://www.armscontrol.org/factsheets/Nuclearweaponswhohaswhat">' +
            'armscontrol.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} had stockpiled <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 1940,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USA',
        data: [
            null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235,
            369, 640, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468,
            20434, 24126, 27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342,
            26662, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
            24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586, 22380,
            21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950, 10871, 10824,
            10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104, 9914, 9620, 9326,
            5113, 5113, 4954, 4804, 4761, 4717, 4368, 4018
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'USSR/Russia',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060,
            1605, 2471, 3322, 4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538,
            11643, 13092, 14478, 15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935,
            30062, 32049, 33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000,
            37000, 35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
            21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000, 15537, 14162, 12787,
            12600, 11400, 5500, 4512, 4502, 4502, 4500, 4500
        ]
    }]
});
```

```css
.detail-container { 
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div class="detail-container">
  <div class="detail-value">
    Value from Graph Here
  </div>
</div>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `mouseOver` event to change the `<div>` content in such a way that it contains all information from the tooltip:

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function() {
                    document.getElementById('customTooltip').innerHTML = 
                        this.series.name + ' had stockpiled <b>' + this.y + 
                        '</b><br/>warheads in ' + this.x
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3my5pdot/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.point.events.mouseOver